# Why does this uvmap come out deformed?

Tags: uv

I have a simple geometry piece that should flatten out perfectly and symmetrically. No complex shapes. But no matter how I uvmap it it comes out little distorted:
[image]

I have added the black lines to show how it "spreads" towards left.

Here is sample file.
https://www48.zippyshare.com/v/x0c19qU7/file.html

another source:
https://ufile.io/coan4lhn

I have reset transforms, I have manually checked that all edges are straight and at 90 degree angles towards each other. No hidden geometry, no modifiers, no edited normals, shape keys, no double vertices, no ngons. Tried uvmapping angled and conformal, turned holes off. Why doesn't it come out straight?

Comment: I cannot download the file.

Comment: There should be a big download button on that site. I just checked it works for me. I'll upload to some other site and update the post shortly

Comment: Well, the new link works for me, too. The first only has a white page with big letters: "403 Forbidden" and a small "nginx" below that line.

Answer (score 0):

When you unwrap switch in the pop up menu in the lower left change the "method" from "Angle Based" to "Conformal". I tried it on the file you shared and it seemed to work. A side note, I would personally put a seam through the center to use more UV space.

UV map after choosing "Conformal":
[image: uv straightened]

Comment: Are you sure you got it straight? Can you show a pic like I posted in the question?No matter what I try there is always little stretching like I show in that pic. I have no idea why there is because with those seams it should flatten out perfectly. Not close but perfect. For whatever reason blender stretches it.

Comment: Now that I could download the file, I tested it. With _Conformal_ the UV edges are perfectly straight. I'll edit Zak's answer and post the picture there.

Comment: I am doing all exactly like you say but it still comes not perfectly straight.

Answer (score 0):

Older topic, but for people seeking answer: In my case changing unwrapping method did not have any effect on the result. However, selecting *Object ‣ Apply ‣ All Transforms* resolved all my UV unwrapping issues.